# Will the wave function of an electron in a wire (or atom) collapse under magnetic interaction?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, wavefunction, wavefunction-collapse

The wave function of a particle is interpreted as a probability distribution. If the particle interacts, the wave function will usually collapse, and the particle will manifest it self at a specific position (With some uncertainty of cause). An electron in a conducting wire has a wave function that is distributed over the entire wire. If this electron creates a current in the wire, this will produce a magnetic field. In case a second charge passes by, we will have a magnetic interaction between the two. Will this collapse the wave function, and thereby force the electron in the wire to manifest it self at more specific position in the wire?
If not, wouldn't it be the case that the wave function acts as a charge distribution in this situation?

Same question could be asked about an electron in an atom, that interacts via the diamagnetic effect.

Answer (score 1):

> If the particle interacts, the wave function will usually collapse, and the particle will manifest it self at a specific position

You are wrong.Electrons can interact with any electric field without the collapse of their wavefunction.

The Hamiltonian in the time (in)dependent Schrodinger equation has a potential which means the wavefunction of a quantum doesnt collapse under the influence of a potential.

> In case a second charge passes by, we will have a magnetic interaction between the two. Will this collapse the wave function, and thereby force the electron in the wire to manifest it self at more specific position in the wire?

No.The back EMF will be acted on all electrons in the circuit thats why the step response of a RL circuit is a exponential function of time.